# BackUp failed "No such file or directory"

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

Using Déjà Dup Backups 42.9

A few months ago I changed the location of Duplicity backups to my local NAS ( smb://wdmycloud/xxxxx/ ) and it's been working fine until last week. But now I get - BackUp failed "No such file or directory".

As far as I'm aware nothing has changed.

I can see the BackUp location, ( DuplictyBackUps ), in Files, where it shows 1.7TB free, but backups now fail.

I created a new backup folder in the same location but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions as to what to look at and what to look for to resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: I've found DeBug Info from Déjà Dup Backups, but it's too long to post here.

Can anyone suggest what I should be looking for to identify and fix the problem.

I can post extracts from the DeBug report if I know might be of value.

Comment: i'd suggest you either join the duplicity mailing list https://lists.nongnu.org/mailman/listinfo/duplicity-talk or create an issue on https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/issues . you will need to register for both.